# Provide outline for rounded rectangle with varying corner radius to clip view in Android

Tags: java, android, rounded-corners, clipping

I'm trying to clip the child views of a ViewGroup using `ClipOutlineProvider`, but the parent view group needs to have its top two corners rounded with different radii (left corner: 36dp, right corner: 4dp) as shown below:

[image]

I've experimented with a custom `ClipOutlineProvider`, but couldn't get to clip the two corners with different radii. I only got as far as clipping all corners with the same radius. Code and result below:

```
private class ClipOutlineProvider extends ViewOutlineProvider {

    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Utils.dpToPixels(36));
    }

}
```

I've added a background color to the RecyclerView item background here to ensure that clipping is applied to child views properly.

[image]

Would appreciate any help in achieving this feat.

P.S. Using a ShapeDrawable XML and setting `View.setClipToOutline()` to `true` didn't work either in this case.